# Can't display 2nd page of search results in Careers searched by location 100km

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs

I searched for Jobs around Bern within 100km.

> https://stackoverflow.com/jobs?sort=i&l=Bern%2C+Schweiz&d=100&u=Km

If I want to go to the second page for the last results, it looses that I searched for 100km and displays only the 20km results.

> https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/developer-jobs-in-bern?sort=i&pg=2

So I do not have the chance to see the jobs on the second page.

Comment: The page does not show either the 100km results but only the 20km, nevertheless it is in the url..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for the heads up, this is now fixed and pushed to prod.